# How to temporarily disable notations in Coq

Tags: coq

Notations are convenient when you're familiar with a project but can be confusing when you're just starting with a code base. I know you can turn off all notations with the vernacular `Set Printing All`. However, I want to keep some printing off, such as implicit arguments. Printing all as follows:

```
Require Import Utf8_core. 
Set Printing All.
Theorem contradiction_implies_anything : forall P Q : Prop,
  (P /\ ~P) -> Q.
Proof.
```

gives the following proof state:

```
1 subgoal (ID 120)

  ============================
  forall (P Q : Prop) (_ : and P (not P)), Q
```

Which is almost there, but I would like the `_` to be removed and the `forall` to be `∀` and just unfold my notations.

I tried `Set Printing Notations` as indicated in the [Coq Reference Manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html#coq:flag.printing-all) but that didn't do anything, nor did enabling

```
Set Printing Implicit.
Set Printing Coercions.
Set Printing Synth.
Set Printing Projections.
```

Comment: Is there a way to "unset everything" so that Coq terms always appear in some standard for in a consistent manner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The funny thing about `Printing Notations` is that you actually have to `Unset` it.

```
Unset Printing Notations.
```

[Here's where the manual hints at it](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#coq:flag.printing-notations):

> `Printing Notations`:
>   Controls whether to use notations for printing terms wherever possible. **Default is on.**

Comment: Is there a way to "unset everything" so that Coq terms always appear in some standard for in a consistent manner?

Comment: `Set Printing All.` might be it.

Comment: Would something like this work? `    Unset Printing Notations.
    Print my_notation_eq_fun_def.` I tried it but my term still has my definition for plus see: `my_notation_eq_fun_def = 
fun x1 x2 : my_nat => eq_refl
  : forall x1 x2 : my_nat, x1 [+] x2 = x1 [+] x2`

Comment: Have you tried `Set Printing All.`? You can also look for related options here in the manual: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/coq-optindex.html#cap-p