# How does one print the entire contents of a proof object or Gallina terms in Coq?

Tags: coq

How does one print and expand everything in a Coq term (e.g. implicits, notations, definition, everything)? I want to print absolutely everything (including the contents of the identifiers).

For example with a term, I tried a modest example with `Set Printing All.` but it didn't work as I expect. My script is:

```
Module print_everything.
  Definition id {A:Type} (x:A) := x.
  Print id.

  Definition id2 := @id.
  Print id2.

  Set Printing All.

  Print id2.
  Print All.
End.
```

but when I sent it to coq I got:

```
id2 = @id
     : forall (A : Type) (_ : A), A
```

but I expect the body of the function, something like this:

```
id2 = fun (A : Type) (x : A) => x
     : forall (A : Type) (_ : A), A
```

or

```
id = fun (A : Type) (x : A) => x
     : forall (A : Type) (_ : A), A
```

How does one remove all "abstractions", including notation, implicit and even identifiers
so that I can see the entire lambda term (ideally when passing a Gallina term to `Print_everything`)?

If possible I'd like to control the scopes of which definitions are unpacked for me too. e.g. global variables `qualid . qualid`.

How does one print and expand everything in a Coq term (e.g. implicits, notations, definition, everything)?

It would also be nice to be able to expand and simplify as much as possible.

---

Related:

- [How to temporarily disable notations in Coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419172/how-to-temporarily-disable-notations-in-coq)
- https://coq.discourse.group/t/how-to-unset-printing-everything-e-g-implicits-notations-etc/1364/4
- it seems `Show Proof.` works in the middle of a proof: [https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/cis500-f14/sf/ProofObjects.html](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis500/cis500-f14/sf/ProofObjects.html) and https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/ProofObjects.html

Comment: You can try using `cbv [...]` to selectively perform δ-reductions, at least for non-Qed terminated proofs. Something like `Set Printing All. Eval cbv in myterm.` can probably get you quite far, actually at the risk of crashing Coq. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: You can also do `Eval cbv delta in myterm.`, which will unfold constants without beta-reducing.

Comment: related: https://coq.discourse.group/t/print-the-curried-version-of-a-function-i-e-explicitly-printing-the-functions-as-an-explicit-chain/1735